# Working with scientific notation values in Javascript / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, bignumber.js

I have an array of Objects that I got from my database. These Objects hold balance values that sometimes are printed in scientific notationn (see error below).

How can I parse these into an Object of Type BigNumber (Bignumber.js)?

My attempt

const b = BigNumber.from(balance);

I am getting this error

```
Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=8.8888888e+25, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)
```

Comment: if your balance variable is array just use BigNumber(balance[ ' ID ' ])

Comment: thank you. Now when I do that and output BIgNumber.toString() I still get scientific notation. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: y = new Number(-123.4567000e+2)       // '-12345.67'